# Why is there no patent system in Hinduism Scriptures in ancient time?

Tags: scripture

Why is there no patent system in Hinduism scriptures in specific branch like Ayurveda, Yoga etc. in ancient time?

Comment: The purpose of Hinduism scripture is  welfare of entire world  , the scriptures are written from this point of view only. The Sages who wrote Hinduism scriptures were knowing that -"All occupational engagements are certainly meant for ultimate liberation. They should never be performed for material gain. Furthermore, according to sages, one who is engaged in the ultimate occupational service should never use material gain to cultivate sense gratification." The soul of Hinduism scripture  is Sacrifice  , Devotion  and liberation of all. -

Comment: @SwiftPushkar : Please write this comment as answer. It’s really good explaination. 

Comment: Good Qn. There is no proof if the patents existed or not earlier. A "patent" is an intellectual property. Usually such intellectual inventions were done by "intellectual"s of the society, which were termed as *"BrAhmana"* class. Now those were least bothered about getting returns of these inventions. The states or countries may not have any centralised documentary about preserving such info as the knowledge was passed from Guru to student via words. An idea usually gets sprinkled upon many humans, if some of them succeed to make a patent, then it's unfair. Read about "Anti-patent initiatives".

Comment: Is there one in the scripture of other religions? You cannot try to retrofit today's systems (lab, thesis, patent system) to the beginning of time.Systems evolve to support the mutated dharmas- dharmas that have changed & devolved & distanced away from their original form and intent. Now if dharma (intent/nature) itself changes without some semblance of a system or code of conduct also dharma),then anarchy + atavism is the only form of society that will survive. Such evolution of a system is required for the sake of civil society. Finally, this is a social-sciences Q and off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Why is there no patent system in Hinduism scriptures in specific branch like Ayurveda, Yoga etc**

Good question , simply because according to ancient Rishi’s ,Sages ,Yogi’s ,  there was no need to take the patent as they were knowing that this knowledge is eternal , they just discovered it. See Vedas from which all knowledge  of Hinduism sprung are also “Apaurusheya” that means the knowledge is eternal ,already present in the universe

Besides this the core teaching and purpose  of the Veda’s  and Shastra’s is  to take care of all the creatures including Nature , and  to lead them towards moksha at the end. So the **scriptures written from this point of view of Universal welfare. And not to gain any personal fame , fortune and for any monetary gain.**

> In genera way  a  patent is an exclusive right granted for an
> invention / Knowledge  the patent owner has the exclusive right to
> prevent or stop others from using invention /knowledge . In other
> words, patent protection means that the invention cannot be publically
> made, used, distributed, imported by others.

The purpose of Hinduism scriptures is to ensure true welfare of all beings. Both
material and spiritual. The Knowledge thus been transmitted orally through GURU-SHISHYA  tradition ,for thousands of years and thus kept intact. physical , mental  ,social and spiritual advancement of the people at large.

The vedas , puranas , upanishds and the other Hinduism texts are written with this point of view only. Because the ancient sages were knowing that  material benefits are temporary and are perishable .That’s why  most traditions consider eternal moksha the ultimate goal. And the scripture is leading the masses towards it by various ways , the Sages , saints , acharyas done this without any material  gaining for themselves .

> मुनय: साधु पृष्टोऽहं भवद्भिर्लोकमङ्गलम् ।
>  यत्कृत: कृष्णसम्प्रश्नो
> येनात्मा सुप्रसीदति ॥ 5 ||
>
> munayaḥ sādhu pṛṣṭo 'haḿ bhavadbhir loka-mańgalam
>  yat kṛtaḥ
> kṛṣṇa-sampraśno yenātmā suprasīdati
>
> O sages, I have been justly questioned by you. Your questions are
> worthy because they relate to Lord Krsna and **so are of relevance to
> the world’s welfare. Only questions of this sort are capable of
> completely satisfying the self.** [**SB 1.2.5**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/2/5)
>
> ---
>
> धर्मस्य ह्यापवर्ग्यस्य नार्थोऽथायोपकल्पते ।
> नार्थस्य धर्मैकान्तस्य कामो लाभाय हि स्मृत:
>
> dharmasya hy āpavargyasya nārtho ’rthāyopakalpate
>  nārthasya
> dharmaikāntasya kāmo lābhāya hi smṛtaḥ
>
> **All occupational engagements are certainly meant for ultimate liberation. They should never be performed for material gain.
> Furthermore, according to sages, one who is engaged in the ultimate
> occupational service should never use material gain to cultivate sense
> gratification**.[**SB 1.2.9**](https://www.vedabase.com/en/sb/1/2/9)
>
> ---

In **Dnyaneshwari which is   commentary on the Bhagavad Gita** written by the Marathi saint and poet Dnyaneshwar in the 13th century The Pasayadan  or the nine ending verses  there is world welfare prayer written - :

> दुरितांचे तिमिर जावो । विश्व स्वधर्म सूर्यें पाहो ।
> जो जे वांच्छिल तो तें लाहो । प्राणिजात ॥
>
> duritāṁce timira jāvo | viśva svadharma sūryeṁ pāho |
> **jo je vāṁcchila to teṁ lāho | prāṇijāta** ||
>
> May the darkness of ignorant disappear | May the Universe see the Sun
> of self-consciousness
> **May whatsoever aspirations of those be fulfilled | of all living
> beings.**

Here Dnyaneshwar is praying for all -   this is also a **kind of universal prayer** to supreme  lord for sake of every creature . And this is the heart and soul of Hinduism scriptures. And not to gain personal /group profit. Nor to restrict the knowledge so as to keep it just for benefit of individual or group.

---

> Ayurveda is a Veda , the  “science of life” it deals with measures for
> healthy living. Besides dealing with principles of maintenance of good
> health the objective of the text is to enable us to lead happy ,and
> disease free life Just like the **“world Health Organization** ”

---

> Conclusion - So as we can see the ultimate purpose of the scripture is
> to lead every one  towards Moksha liberation .The sages , Rishies ,
> seers ,saints  and writers of Hinduism  scriptures do not took patents
> of their writings or the knowledge they gained. Simply they do not
> wanted any material gain from doing this. Even some of them have not
> took the credit by mentioning their name. And there was no need to
> take  patent  /copyright of scriptures.And the system was /is not there.

Comment: Thank you , I will update and re-format the answer in some time and will add more verses from scriptures related to the question.